# create a macro to copy multiple rows of data from one sheet to another based on a criteria

Tags: vba, loops, criteria, copy-paste

I am trying to write a macro that will let me copy a range of data from one sheet to another sheet based on a criteria in the column before the column to be copied.

Column B is the criteria column. If there is a 1 in any row in this column then columns C thru AN will be copied from that row where there is a 1 and be pasted into another sheet starting at the top of that sheet.

I have the following code. It locates the first row that satisfies the criteria and copies this row to the second sheet, however the code does not loop thru to find other rows that satisfy the criteria. How can I adjust the code to loop and copy each instance where the criteria is satisfied?

```
Sub testIt()

Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("DataDump").Activate

    For i = 2 To Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row()
        If Range("B" & i).Value = 1 Then
            Range("C" & i, "AN" & i).Copy
            Sheets("PriceData").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("B2", "AM2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub testIt()

Dim i As Long, shtSrc As Worksheet, rngDest As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("DataDump")
    Set rngDest = Sheets("PriceData").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    For i = 2 To shtSrc.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
        If shtSrc.Range("B" & i).Value = 1 Then
            shtSrc.Range("C" & i & ":AN" & i).Copy rngDest
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```